# Hide and display div <li> elements using JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The first column is displayed by default. If I click on the "1" I want to display "1.1, 1.2, 1.3" and then if I click on "1.1" display "1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3", but if I click on "1.2" hide the "1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3" and display "1.2.1, ...". If I click on "2" hide "1.1, 1.2, 1.3" and hide "1.2.1, ..." and display "2.1, 2.2" .....

This is always nested in 3 layers.

The HTML code have to look like as I wrote in my scource code.

It will not be a menu system.

I do not have any idea how to make this work.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>$(document).ready(function(){$("#load").attr("src","table.html");});</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" id="load" src="table.html" ></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

table.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div>   
    <div class="main">

        <div class="First">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        </div>

        <div class="Second">
            
            <div class="S_1">
                <li><a href="#">1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1.3</a></li>
            </div>

            <div class="S_2">
                <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="Third">
            
            <div class="T_1">
                
                <div class="T_1.1">
                    <li>1.1.1</li>
                    <li>1.1.2</li>
                </div>
                ....

            </div>
            ....
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
* {margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}
li {list-style: none;}
.main {display:flex;justify-content: center;}
.First {background:green;width:33.33vw;}
.Second {background:gold; width:33.33vw;}
.Third {background:gray;width:33.33vw;}
```

[image]

Comment: when click, it toggle hide(fold) state for it's children, and hide all others.

Comment: It's better if you provide some js/jq to show you've *attempted* to resolve this issue yourself, for StackOverflow. [Toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is a good starting point, but if you google your question, I'm sure you'll find examples fitting the description you've provided

Comment: @appleapple Yes. So basicaly, if I click on a new parents, hide the previous parent, and hide its all children.

Comment: @ taiwan12, yes

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. `<li>` tags only allow a few elements as parent elements. see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li that given, your nesting is not a valid nesting

Comment: It seems illogical to hide 1.1 , 1.2 , 1.3 on click of 1.2 ------ According to me you should have hide 1.1.1 , 1.1.2 , 1.1.3 on click of 1.2, If you can confirm that then i can make one for you.


Do remember for that i will need to change HTML your.

Comment: @Rush.2707 I have just edited my post.

Comment: I didn't really read the question and answers, but if the answer by Frenchy (which you accepted) worked for you, you should give the bounty, although I think it will auto-give the bounty.  You can get [a badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/221/benefactor) for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution which builds the concept from first class:

```js
var $sel = $(".First li");
var nbr = $sel.length;
var lastval ="";
$sel.clone().appendTo(".Second").clone().appendTo(".Third");
$(".main div:not([class=First])").hide();

$(document).on("click", "li", function() {
  var val = $(this).text();
  var l = val.length;
  if(lastval == val || l > 3) return;
  lastval = val;
  switch(val.length){
    case 1:
      $(".main div").show().last().hide();
      $(".Second li").map((i, e) => $(e).find("a").text(val + "." + (i + 1)));
      break;
    case 3:
       $(".Third").show().find("li").map((i, e) => $(e).find("a").text(val + "." + (i + 1)));     
      break;    
    
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
}

.First {
  background: green;
  width: 33.33vw;
}

.Second {
  background: gold;
  width: 33.33vw;
}

.Third {
  background: gray;
  width: 33.33vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="First">
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="Second">
    </div>
    <div class="Third">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this is the scrap code where you can start. It is simple logic. The code is creating HTML and changing the other div's HTML.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', 'a', function() {
    var number = $(this).html();
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent().attr('class');
    var htmlss = '';
    var i;
    if(parent == 'First'){
      $('.Second').html('');
      $('.Third').html('');
      for(i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        htmlss += '<li><a href=#>' + number + '.' + i +'</a></li>';
      }
      $('.Second').html(htmlss);
    }
    else if (parent == 'Second'){
      $('.Third').html('');
      for(i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        htmlss += '<li><a href=#>' + number + '.' + i +'</a></li>';
      }
      $('.Third').html(htmlss);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}
li {list-style: none;}
.main {display:flex;justify-content: center;}
.First {background:green;width:33.33vw;}
.Second {background:gold; width:33.33vw;}
.Third {background:gray;width:33.33vw;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="First">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="Second">
        </div>
        <div class="Third">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure *JavaScript* solution. I did not touch the *HTML* as that was declared forbidden, so I had to come up with some *js* mumbo jumbo to get the initial layout. Following is a working snippet:

```js
  function clickMe(id) {
    let query;

    if (id.length == 1) {
      query = document.querySelector(".S_1");

      second.style.opacity = 1;
      third.style.opacity = 0;
    } else if (id.length == 3) {
      query = document.querySelector(".T_1").children[0];
      selector = ".T_1.1";
      third.style.opacity = 1;
    }

    [...query.children].forEach((node, i) => {
      node.innerText = `${id}.${i + 1}`;
    });
  }

      const hideNotUseful = document.querySelector(".S_2").remove();
      const first = document.querySelector(".First");
      const thirdChild = document.createElement("li");
      thirdChild.innerText = 3;
      first.append(thirdChild);

      const second = document.querySelector(".Second");
      const third = document.querySelector(".Third");
      second.style.opacity = 0;
      third.style.opacity = 0;

      [...first.children, ...second.children[0].children].forEach(node => {
        node.addEventListener("click", e => clickMe(node.innerText));
      });
```

```css
      * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      li {
        list-style: none;
      }
      .main {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .First {
        background: green;
        width: 33.33vw;
      }
      .Second {
        background: gold;
        width: 33.33vw;
      }
      .Third {
        background: gray;
        width: 33.33vw;
      }
```

```html
   <div>
      <div class="main">
        <div class="First">
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        </div>

        <div class="Second">
          <div class="S_1">
            <li><a href="#">1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.3</a></li>
          </div>

          <div class="S_2">
            <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="Third">
          <div class="T_1">
            <div class="T_1.1">
              <li>1.1.1</li>
              <li>1.1.2</li>
              <li>1.1.3</li>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```